# In outlook web addin, the Event "onAppointmentAttendeesChangedHandler" works on outlook web. But it fails to trigger on outlook desktop

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm new to web-addin and trying to build an addin for outlook meeting. I need to capture the event when ever there is a change in attendees (participants).
I have subscribed to onAppointmentAttendeesChangedHandler, which works perfectly on outlook web.
But when I try the same on outlook desktop client (windows, office build is 2108), the event is not triggered. Please suggest

below is the JS code.

```
// subscribing to the Attendee change event.
Office.actions.associate("onAppointmentAttendeesChangedHandler", onAppointmentAttendeesChangedHandler);

//Function to be called when the event is triggered.
function onAppointmentAttendeesChangedHandler(event) {
GetReciepientsCount(_event);
// console.log("Before setting Obj");
}
```

where as, the below subscription works on both outlook web and windows desktop client.

```
Office.actions.associate("onAppointmentComposeHandler", onAppointmentComposeHandler);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Windows based Outlook application the minimum required build is 16.0.14511.10000. If required, join the [Office Insider program](https://insider.office.com/join/windows) and choose the `Beta Channel` for access to Office beta builds.

You can read more about the requirements for event-based activation in the [Configure your Outlook add-in for event-based activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch) article.